# Why does copy pasting in python from atom give me errors?

Tags: python

I'm a ultra noob python user just started with it
my code:

```
def cost_trip(days):
  cost = days*10
 if days>7:
   return cost-20
 elif days<=7:
  return cost
def vac_ation(days):
  return 'cost_trip'(days)
print vac_ation(5)
```

I get so many errors about syntax intendation please help
and why does copy pasting from atom not work?

Answer (score 1):

Python demands you to use indenting. Either a fixed amount of spaces or tab per ident (do not mix them).  In your example the "if" needs to be under the "c" of "cost. The original probably did not have enough spaces.

I used 4 spaces (and 2 empty lines after the end of a "def") and this will validate ...

```
def cost_trip(days):
    cost = days*10
    if days>7:
       return cost-20
    elif days<=7:
       return cost


def vac_ation(days):
    return cost_trip(days)


print vac_ation(5)
```

Comment: So, I should make sure next time, that I use 4 spaces for intending and empty lines between different pieces of code?

Comment: 4 spaces is common practice; see the link ->  2 empty lines is convention so not mandatory (see PEP 8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ )

Comment: why are the spaces 3 when you use return?

Comment: In a python editor indent is done by indenting the same as the line above it. Could it be there are 3 there? It should be 4... :)